# How to make the WPF app to, open only one new window or create only single instance of the XAML, when clicking button in MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application and here is the application structure:

> **Views**
>
> > MainWindow.xaml, ABC.xaml (all with .cs files)
>
> **ViewModels**
>
> > MainWindowVM.cs, ABCVM.cs

I have a Button in *MainWindow.xaml* (bound to *MainWindowVM.cs*) that calls a function, SampleFunction() in *MainWindowVM.cs* when being clicked and the SampleFunction() then creates a new instance of *ABC.xaml* (bound to *ABCVM.cs*) and open a new window of *ABC.xaml* using Show() function.

How can I make sure that clicking the Button in MainWindow would not open another new window of *ABC.xaml* when the old window is still there, or not create another new instance of *ABC.xaml*?

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    /*...Some other codes...*/

    private MainWindowVM _VM = new MainWindowVM();
    public MainWindowVM MainWindowVM 
    { 
        get { return _VM; } 
        set { _VM= value; } 
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = MainWindowVM;      
    }
    private void SomeControl_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender,MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       MainWindowVM.SampleFunction();
    }
}
```

**MainWindowVM.cs**

```cs
public class MainWindowVM
{
    /*...Some other codes...*/

     public void SampleFunction()
     {
         ABC abc= new ABC();
         abc.Show();
     }
}
```

**ABC.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class ABC: Window
{
    /*...Some other codes...*/

    private static ABCVM _abcVM= new ABCVM();
    public ABCVM ABCVM { get { return _abcVM; } set { _abcVM = value; } }
    public ABC()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = ABCVM;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But you can use the ShowDialog() instead of Show(). Then you have to close the ABC.xaml first, before you can make something on the MainWindow (for example open another ABC)

Comment: @Presi Yes, it's the solution. Thank you.

Comment: I post it as an answer. Please accept it that everyone see the solution fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ShowDialog() instead of Show().

Then you have to close the ABC.xaml first, before you can make something on the MainWindow. So you can't open a second ABC.xaml Window.

Answer (score 1):

You can write code to check whether a window type object exists or not.

```
            for each(Window win in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                string windowType = win.GetType().ToString();
                if (!windowType.Equals(nameSpace + "." + ABC))
                {
                   ABC abc= new ABC();
                   abc.Show();
                }
            }
```